# BTC-e API clarifications

Tags: api, btce, trade

Considering the trade information reported here: https://btc-e.com/api/3/trades/btc_usd

1. Do these refer to open orders, or to completed trades?  If this shows only completed trades, does the API offer a means to retrieve the open orders?
2. Each record has an 'amount' field.  Is this field always in USD for both bids and asks?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation (unfortunately it's in russian, but google can translate): https://btc-e.com/api/3/documentation

1. I think it's finished trades. Look at the Depth method to get open orders https://btc-e.com/api/3/documentation#depth
2. If you are looking at the btc_usd pair, then the price is in USD, and the amount in BTC